# Mod rewrite (htaccess) on get variable not working

Tags: .htaccess, url

I am testing out mod rewrite for my site. I thought i would try a simple code, but it's not working.  I have a .htaccess file in my root directory (localhost).  In localhost I have a page titled profile.php.  Profile.php can take a get variable `p` from my database.  So it looks like `localhost/profile.php?p=3` where `3` is a unique id.  When i go to localhost/profile.php?p=3 it works, but when i go to localhost/3, it doesn't.  I get a 404 not found.

.HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/profile.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

EDIT:

httpd.conf (currently):

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: That works fine for me, note that with `http://localhost` in front, apache is going to redirect and not internally rewrite.

Comment: @JonLin what does that mean?  im new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file  in the root directory of your site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#assume that p is only numeric
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ profile.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

Edit:

Check your httpd.conf to see if `AllowOverride` is set to all as below. If set to none, then .htaccess will not work

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: is there a simple way to test if this .htaccess file is working.  i checked apache to make sure the mod_rewrite was on and it is

Comment: @user802370 put something invalid in your htaccess e.g. `213werw42` and if you get a 500 error, it is working

Comment: i put that exact statement in and there was no 500 error. it worked as normal

Comment: @kirby so it looks like your .htaccess is not enabled. See last edit

Comment: it actually did say none so i edited it.  i put my edited version in the original question as an eddit

Comment: also if this matters, in my apache2 folder i also have httpd.conf.save and httpd.conf.save.1 along with the httpd.conf.  i was just wondering if these two other files have an impact

Comment: @kirby Those files were most likely created by you text editor (autosave) and should not matter to apache. If you are on windows, are you sure you created the `.htaccess` file correctly?

Comment: @Gerben im on a mac and im pretty sure the .htaccess file is correct.

Comment: @kirby If yous still do not get an error when you have invalid entries in your .htaccess, then it is either still not enabled or as Gerben said it is not named correctly.  If you are getting errors, then you can turn up error logging and see error logs by putting something similar to these 2 lines in your httpd.conf `RewriteLog /var/log/rewrite.log' and `RewriteLogLevel 9`

Comment: @UlrichPalha i have a feeling that it's not named correctly.  is there a place where i can download a .htaccess.  i tried searching google but nothing came up

Comment: @kirby If you have correctly verified the name, literally dot followed by an htaccess or `.htaccess` i.e. not .htaccess.txt etc. Then there its not necessary to download Also try checking the Apache log I mentioned above regardless to see if there are any clues there. Also note that anything you put in a .htaccess file can be put in a Directory section in httpd.conf http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: @kirby I would also change `Deny from all` to `Allow from all`, not sure how it works with the former. Last suggestion is to create a new question along the lines of .htaccess does not work on ServerFault.com, post httpd.conf if possible and mention all else you have tried and results.

Comment: @UlrichPalha i also tried the error log it seems that ive gotten about a hundred errors and all of them are the same thing. "[Thu Jan 19 21:50:56 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico